# Buttons change font size to some non-specified

Tags: css, javafx

I have some buttons. Without CSS it saves font size of buttons when you click or hover the button. But if I apply CSS, it changes:

**Without CSS**

[image: Without CSS]

**With CSS**

[image: With CSS]

The font size changes (if I set not default size in FXML, the highest button has default font size) and it starts being smaller height (possible to see in 2nd gif)

CSS:

```css
.button {
  -fx-border-style: null;
  -fx-background-radius: 0;

  -fx-background-color: #560145;

  -fx-font-family: "Open Sans", "Open Sans", "Open Sans", "Open Sans";
  -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.button:hover {
  -fx-background-color: #87016c;
  -fx-text-fill: #e6e6e6;
}

.button:pressed {
  -fx-background-color: #4d0036;
  -fx-text-fill: #e6e6e6;
}


.button:disabled {
  -fx-opacity: 0.4;
  -fx-background-color: grey;
  -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

FXML

```xml
  <Button layoutX="342.0" layoutY="329.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="164.0" text="Button">
     <font>
        <Font size="6.0" />
     </font>
  </Button>
```

I don't do anything in java code with buttons! Only CSS and FXML font-size setting.

What's wrong?

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing, maybe? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: you did read the referenced help page, didn't you ;) Then follow its suggestion!

Comment: @kleopatra as I understand, it's fully right..

Comment: _but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time_ (from: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - concededly not from the other, thought it was there as well ;)

Comment: @kleopatra Enough right now? That's all I do with the button.

Comment: no, of course not - where's the mcve? (never seen anything near the behaviour you describe and slightly annoyed that you insist on _not_ showing an example as suggested in the help page ..) Anyway, I'm off now and without a runnable example your question probably will be closed - you have wasted a whole afternoon during which you _might_ have gotten help (from me or others)

Comment: @kleopatra I'm able of reproducing the issue with the code provided half an hour before your comment. (I changed the creation of the button from fxml code to `Button button = new Button("button"); button.setFont(Font.font(6));`)

Comment: @fabian so what? you were lucky as we all know - neither playing guessing games nor spoon-feeding helps anyone, in particular not the OP and her co-workers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing height solver adding

```
-fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0, 1, 2;
```

in .button section.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly went wrong, but you shouldn't combine `Button` properties AND CSS to choose the font.

Defining both font family and font size in the CSS stylesheet should work fine. (`-fx-font-family` allows only for a single string though.)

```css
.button {
  -fx-border-style: null;
  -fx-background-radius: 0.0;

  -fx-background-color: #560145;
  -fx-font-size: 6.0;
  -fx-font-family: "Open Sans";
  -fx-text-fill: white;
}

...
```

As an alternative use inline CSS to change the button's font size:

```xml
<Button layoutX="342.0" layoutY="329.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="164.0" text="Button" style="-fx-font-size: 6;"/>
```

and remove the `-fx-font-size` property from the CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks. But it changes all the buttons to this font size, but I would like to set it using FXML for each button and let all buttons get other options (color, text-fill,...) from css, that's why I use css. Is it possible?

Comment: And.. If I set font and font size in css, it still changes the height of the button... (like 2nd gif)